# block the view of my project's commit history

Tags: git, security

How do I block the view of my project's commit history? My case: I have a project and I ended up putting important security data, and only afterwards I deleted it, but it is still in the history, there is a way to block the history or the file, or even delete this file from the old commits.

still nothing, I'm thinking of deleting the project and uploading again.

Comment: If you have a public repository then you should delete it and reupload. Reupload without the leaked stuff.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+sensitive+data